# jquery ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have many places in my code doing "$.ajax" call 
can I define one place to handle all errors ?

I know there is "error: function ... " that I can place in each call , but I want to write it just one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup({});
```

Comment: How very...terse. @OP: It sets default options for Ajax requests. Link: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup#options

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(XMLHttpRequest + ':' + textStatus + ':' + errorThrown);
            return false;
        }
    });


is this OK ?

Comment: @haddar: There's sample code in the docs I linked (click the "Examples" tab). But that looks about right, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

How 'bout the [`ajaxError` event](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback)?

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** use the $.ajaxSetup() event handler method (as stated by the JQuery docs):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

> *Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler
>   methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(),
>   .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather
>   than within the options object for
>   $.ajaxSetup().*

Use the **$.ajaxError()** method instead:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError

Answer (score 0):

You can define your error handling function just once and then refer to it in the Ajax call rather than using function literals in each call.